# Optimize continuous deployment (cancel throu chain-of-responsibility)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Id like to improove continuous delivery. I am using a Tomcat 8 and maven.

I use `mvn tomcat:redeploy` to deploy the webapp.

In [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_using_a_Context_configuration_%22.xml%22_file) I found this part:

> Deploy A New Application Archive (WAR) Remotely
>
> If installation and startup is successful, you will receive(...)
>
> Otherwise, the response will start with FAIL and include an error message.

As possible causes of `FAIL` one point is of interrest:

> An exception was encountered trying to start the new web application.

So Id like to throw an exception at startup so in the `web.xml` I write:

> <​load-on-startup>1<​/load-on-startup>

to the `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`-Servlet. Then I write a Singleton:

```
@Service
public class AvoidStartupOnMissingDatabase implements SmartInitializingSingleton {

    @Override
    public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Do not deploy this app!");
    }
}
```

This causes this Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Do not deploy this app!
        at xxx.AvoidStartupOnMissingDatabase.afterSingletonsInstantiated(AvoidStartupOnMissingDatabase.java:11)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4962)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3823)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1410)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1320)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1525)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:443)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:486)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Problem

The application unfortunately deployed!

[image: Screenshot of ci]

### Question

I fail the init. I said load-on-start. Tomcat said fail if not start. Tomcat said (re)deploy if can start.

So the exception must fail the deployment. Right?

### EDIT

I tested tomcat-8.5.30 as well as tomcat-8.5.37, both unfortunately succeed.

Comment: Is this your main objective? : Detect faults during the deployment and / or the start of your application?

Comment: @JR Id like to rollback deployment on err.

Comment: Do you have some continuous integration server or could you provision one?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, I use RM. On commit (Subversion) I unit-test integration-test and redeploy (deliver) the app. If the redeploy (deliver) fail the commit (Subversion) is canceled and the changes are not added to the svn.

Comment: I have not heard about RM. Maven offer several plugins to deploy but personally, I don't like to mix build configurations with security credentials in my pom.xml. Last questions in order answer your question: Deploy with maven is mandatory? Do you have a an artifact repository like [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) or are you able to provisioning a new one?

Comment: I use RM as artifact repository. Mandatory is only rollback broken deployment. RM is also my PKI-Server, OCSP, Maven site hoster, wiki, bugtracker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iv created a [bug in Tomcat](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63161). The developer guided me to the solution
similar to Alexandru Cojocaru.

I moved from a Servlet to a SerlvetContextListener and I successfully receive a "FAIL" for the deployment.

After this invalid deployment the old application is unfortunately **not** restarted. But the commit to svn is canceled Successfully and is not added to the svn-change-log!

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has two options to deploy war files:

- copy war to webapps
- http tomcat endpoint /manager/text/deploy

More details and configurations in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292858/3957754)

Also, tomcat:redeploy is not for rollback purposes, is just for deploy an existing war without necessity or package again.

I'm sure that the `mvn tomcat:deploy` plugin uses the **/manager/text/deploy** tomcat endpoint to deploy war files.

Assuming that you are using some continuous integration server (jenkins, travis, etc) or just a simple shell script to invoke the previous steps, I advice you these approaches to perform a rollback:

## Rollback parameter

Add a new input parameter in your flow, called : rollback_tag or previous_version.

## Rollback with Maven

Maven is the best option for compile and generate war or jar files. But for deployment purposes, I think it is not the best option. I would not like share credentials or configurations in my pom.xml (with or without variables):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <server>TomcatServer</server>
      <path>/javaCodeGeeks</path>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Anyway if you want to use maven, you need:

- Search the source code of the maven plugin
- Extend it or add new functionalities like:

  - Catch errors from tomcat deployment
  - Download the source code using some tag version
  - Redeploy in case of error

## Rollback downloading again

Steps could be:

- (1) Download the source using svn
- (2) Execute mvn clean package
- (3) Execute mvn tomcat:deploy

  - This command must return an exit code
  - (3.1) In case of exit_code == 0 , would indicate that your deploy was successful.
  - (3.2) In case of exit_code != 0 , would indicate an error in deployment. Continue with (4) step
- (4) Download the source using svn but in this case you must use the [rollback tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744763/3957754) parameter and repeat the steps (2) and (3)

## With some artifact repository

With this tool, We need to download source code using svn , just one time. After compile and success deploy, you must **upload** the war or jar file with specific version like 1.0.0 Next steps in your flow just need to download the war/jar file.

In case of error in 1.0.1 deployment, you just need to download the previous stable version 1.0.0 from your artifact repository.
Steps could be:

- (1) Detect the **svn commit** action of the developer and compile, test and upload the war file to the artifact repository using your continuous integration server or your shell script.
- (2) Download the war file from the artifact repository
- (3)Execute a curl command to upload and deploy war file. More details and configurations here:

  - [How to deploy war to tomcat using jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288611/how-to-deploy-war-to-tomcat-using-jenkins-pipeline/54292858#54292858)
  - [Tomcat manager remote deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622865/3957754)
- (4) In case of error, download the war file from the artifact repository but in this case you must use the **previous_version** parameter and repeat the step (3)

Comment: Why do you think you must store credentials in the pom.xml? That you did not tell about the double-hash deployment let me think you focus the bounty but not the solution.

Comment: According to the comments : "@JR Id like to rollback deployment on err.", you are trying to rollback on error using maven. I only share some approaches to perform a rollback.

Comment: @JR SQL can not rollback commited updates. A compleated deployment is a commited deployment. A compleated deployment can not be rolled back but you can deploy an old one.

Comment: Do you need to deploy a previous war version in case a new version of the war fails to deploy? I tried to help you base on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment was successful. The stack trace that you see was caused by an application runtime error, when Spring tried to load the `AvoidStartupOnMissingDatabase` bean. At this point, the application is already deployed and running.

If you want to make the Maven `redeploy` goal fail, you need to cause an error during deployment, not while the application is running. You can do this by using a [wrong URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433492/maven-tomcat-deploy-failed) in the Maven Tomcat plugin configuration, for example.

Comment: If you read the question you will notice the `org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy` in the stacktrace. This is an error during deployment my friend.